# Basic Math Problem with Differential Equations: Integrating Factors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Please can anyone break down in detailed steps how these 2 lines are equal to each other. I'm confused.

Also please ignore the " = 0 " in the second line.

\begin{align*}
(1+x^2)\,&\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{d(1+x^2)}{dx}\cdot y \\
&\frac{d}{dx}\,(y(1+x^2))=0
\end{align*}

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Going from bottom to top you use the product rule. The tricky thing was coming up with the idea to turn the top into the bottom.

Comment: This has already been asked today ... have a look at "Basic math problem with Integrating Factors: Differential Equations"

Comment: @Bruce Providing a link would be friendlier. Use the “share” button underneath the question! Then paste it into the comment, like so: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2877312/23290

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is using the product rule backwards. To see things clearly take $a = 1+ x^2$ and keep $y$ as it is.

We know that from product rule,

$\frac{d(ay)}{dx} = y \frac{da}{dx} + a \frac{dy}{dx}$

here the equality is used backwards,

$ y \frac{da}{dx} + a \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d(ay)}{dx}$

If you are new to product rule and wonder about how it is true, start thinking from the first principles of derivative definition or look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule.

Answer (score 0):

$$
(1+x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{d(1+x^2)}{dx}\cdot y =\frac{d}{dx}\,(y(1+x^2))
$$
Differentiate the right side

You differentiate a product of two functions, just apply the rule 
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f \times g)= g\frac{d}{dx}f+f\frac{d}{dx}g$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\,(y(1+x^2))=(1+x^2)\frac {d}{dx}y+y\frac {d}{dx}(x^2+1)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\,(y(1+x^2))=(1+x^2)y'+2xy$$
note that 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\,(1+x^2)=2x$$